# How is NodeJS able to hash a Buffer?

Tags: php, node.js

I have an existing NodeJS lib whose hashed Buffer functionality I am trying to match in PHP (specifically the "AFTER" value below), but have so far failed. What is NodeJS doing to a Buffer internally such that it can be hashed and returned as a new Buffer?

```
...
let concatValue = isHex(currentbranchOps[o].r) ? Buffer.from(currentbranchOps[o].r, 'hex') : Buffer.from(currentbranchOps[o].r, 'utf8')
currentHashValue = Buffer.concat([currentHashValue, concatValue])

console.log('BEFORE: ', currentHashValue); // Uint8Array(76) [110, 111, 100, 101......]
currentHashValue = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(currentHashValue).digest()
console.log('AFTER: ', currentHashValue); // Uint8Array(32) [123, 67, 203, 88......]
...
```

Given that only stringy types can be hashed, how is Node arriving at the "AFTER" value above in the form of another Buffer?

In PHP I have tried:

```
hash('sha256', pack('H*', implode('', [110, 111, 100, 101......] )))
hash('sha256', pack('c*', implode('', [110, 111, 100, 101......] )))
```

I also wrote a routine that gives me a digest of the array as a string, and then hashing the result (and various permutations thereof), without being able to match exactly what Node gives me in the "AFTER" block.

```
function buffer_digest_from(array $dec) : string
{
    $hex = '';

    foreach($dec as $int) {
        // Left pad single hex values with zeroes, to match chainpoint hashes
        $hex .= str_pad(dechex($int), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }

    return $hex;
}

hash('sha256', pack('H*', buffer_digest_from([110, 111, 100, 101......] )));
hash('sha256', pack('c*', buffer_digest_from([110, 111, 100, 101......] )));
hash('sha256', buffer_digest_from([110, 111, 100, 101......] ));
```

I realise of course that languages vary in their implementations, but if all I wish to do is manipulate integers, then there should be some way to arrive at the same solution, regardless of implementation.

Many thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question might stem from a misunderstanding of what Node.js buffers are. They are really just a sequence of bytes. The default way to output them in the console and interact with them looks like an array of numbers.

PHP also has a similar data type that stores lists of bytes, but it's interface looks less like an array. It's actually the humble `string`.

PHP's string is not like Javascript's string. Javascript's string is more like a 'series of characters', but PHP's string is just a list of bytes.

So if you have a (PHP) array like:

```
$input = [110, 111, 100, 101.....];
```

To convert that into a string, you would actually just do:

```
$buffer = '';
foreach($input as $byte) {
  $buffer .= chr($byte);
}
```

The reason Node.js Buffer exist, is because Javascript didn't originally have a 'series of bytes' data structure, and you can't really use javascript's string to store any list of bytes.

So even though their interfaces are different, the following 3 data types are more or less equivalent:

- PHP's `string`
- Node.js' `Buffer`
- C's array of `char` (there is no native C string type)

PHP was going to have a data structure similar to Javascript's string in PHP 6, but PHP 6 was canned.

Comment: OK, awesome. It took several re-reads of your response to sort this. To get the equivalent hash as I get out of a Node Buffer, I used your logic above which gives me a raw byte-string, then `hash('sha256', $buffer)` = result! Thank you!